# Create a mac dashboard widget compatible with 32-bit and 64-bit systems

Tags: macos, widget, dashboard, mac-dashboard-widget

I have to develop a dashboard widget for Mac Osx to support 32/64 bit systems.
This looks to me that there is nothing else to do if the widget does not use any programmed plugin, just HTML, JS & CSS.

Is this correct? Just need to be sure.

Thanks a lot,
Leonardo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not using any Objective-C code then it will definitely be portable.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

"Based on Web Kit technologies, Dashboard Widgets are created using a mix of HTML, JavaScript, and CSS."

So no need to worry.